# OpenSearch Dashboard report downloading errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

Currently have issues with AWS Opensearch dashboard.

1. **Can't download the AWS OpenSearch dashboard as either PDF or PNG**

Created Opensearch dashboard and need to download as PDF. After i click the reporting tab next to "EDIT" Generate Reports appears with Download PDF and PNG. But after i click the PDF OR PNG It keeps refreshing and cant download.

[image]

2. What is the **Difference between "Row" and "Formatted"** Download excels on dashboard. Both are downloaded as CSV files. Any differences between them?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We are facing the same issue and the AWS has communicated to us that their developers are working on a fix.

As a short cut, the CLI mentioned here is being suggested to be used https://github.com/opensearch-project/dashboards-reports/issues/345

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same problem while downloading reports in Opensearch .

Issue is there are some additional libraries required to run the report extraction in headless mode. I installed  required dependencies and issue is resolved.

Please refer this link https://github.com/opensearch-project/dashboards-reports/blob/main/dashboards-reports/rendering-engine/headless-chrome/README.md#additional-libaries